# I'm having errors in unity when making a character controller

Tags: unity-game-engine

I getting the message "error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected" in unity but not in Visual Studio. I just need my character to to move horizontally. I've searched a few forums about this error and the common causes where typos, miss placed brackets, and incorrect variables.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public float Character_Controller_2D : MonoBehaviour,
{
private float playerInput;  
private float speed = 0;
private Rigidbody2D rigidBody;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
  rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
  speed = GetComponent<speed> ();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    Vector3 playerInput = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontial"), 0);
    transform.position = transform.position + playerInput.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the comma after MonoBehaviour.

Comment: And change "float" on that line to "class". It should read: public class Character_Controller_2D : MonoBehaviour